# Why does an HttpGet works without timeouts but with timeouts causes an internal server error?

Tags: java, android, http

I don't know how the HttpClient works exactly but I find it quite strange that I get an internal server error if I initialise the httpclient with `new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters)` but everythings works fine if I initialise it with `new DefaultHttpClient()`. I should additionally mention that the error does not occur on the first request. Here's a piece of my code, are there any errors?

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 3000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
HttpClient httpclient
```

to

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. (Of course, how should it? The object stays the same, or?)